# How can I re-size Background Image to full Width of Window with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage, and in it I use a background image that I would like to be stretched to the full width of the window, because I have text on it, which I want to be in a fixed position no matter what the screen resolution is. I'm looking for a CSS implementation, though if Javascript is my best bet, I will be wiling to use that.

Here's what my page looks like: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9134840/demo/windowsxp.html

Unless you're using a 1080p monitor, the background image doesn't fully extend from edge to edge, and leaves a little white space.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
html {
}

body {
}

#img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.title {
    position:absolute;
    top:180px; 
    left:350px;
    width:700px; 
    color:Purple;
    font-style:oblique;
    font-family:cursive;  
    text-shadow: 1px 1px;
}

#pre {
    position:absolute;
    top:280px; /* in conjunction with left property, decides the text position */
    left:150px;
    width:700px;
    font-size:large;
    font-family:cursive;
}

#header {
    position:absolute;
    top:530px; 
    left:450px;
    width:700px;
    font-size:x-large;
    font-family:cursive;
}

#sub {
    position:absolute;
    top:580px; 
    left:160px;
    width:1090px;
    font-size:x-large;
    font-family:cursive;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="background">
<img src="back2.png" id="img" class="stretch" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `background-size` property of CSS

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still fairly new to this, I used the background-size but as cover on my image,  but now my text is flowing all around the place and not staying in a fixed position on the page.

Comment: You can apply the background-image and background-size properties to your body element. That way it should not affect the other elements on your page.

Comment: I really hate to seem like a big noob, but I've read at least 10 different articles and I still can't get it to work.  Your method works fine for resizing the image, yet I would like my text to stay resize as well thus everything remains in the same position

Comment: Ok, so if i understand correctly, you want not just the background image to stretch but the content as well. Can be done by specifying the width of your content container in percentage w.r.t. the parent.

Comment: Ok, saw your page. Quite a few things to change there to work as you require it to. a) Do not use absolute positioning for everything. Use them as inline blocks and specify their CSS width in %. For ex: your title DIV can be say 100% width with text-align center, rest of the elements can be 100% width with text-align left.

Comment: BTW, cool info there. Maybe should try it sometime on my galaxy note! Will it brick it? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can extend width past 100%. One option to try. 
Otherwise I agree with techfoobar, use the background css property, specifically background-size.

Comment: This was an option I was considering, but I liked techfoobar's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set margins to 0 and widths to 100% for your image and its containers. Using a `<div>` is not necessary.  For example:

```
body
{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
}


#background
{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
}


#img
{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```